# Does Punisher have superpowers?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

During Season 2 of Netflix's *Daredevil* we meet Frank Castle (aka The Punisher).

Looking at his seemingly unnatural ability in combat and survival (video below), is it plausible that he has superpowers?

Comment: Unless they changed him drastically for this show, The Punisher has no superpowers. He is "just" a very determined and capable individual. Heroes usually survive impossible hits on big screen (which was nicely addressed at the end of "[Last Action Hero](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107362/)").

Comment: @VedranŠego "Unless they changed him", yes that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: I can't see them changing Frank that much. It's too big of a deviation from The Punisher's character.

Comment: Well, given that Captain America is merely “at peak human potential” in a variety of areas, and yet exhibits clearly superhuman abilities, I think we can safely say that what baseline humans are capable of with good genetics and training in the Marvel Universe (and the MCU) is a little more than in real life. Consider e.g. Black Widow and Hawkeye’s combat abilities, or even Fitz and Simmons’s scientific expertise.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I know that what I'm seeing on-screen (both w/ Punisher & Cap) is superhuman/superpowers, but I'm wondering if within their universe, in the Netflix adaptation, there is something to suggest Frank is more than just an elite soldier. Does he have superhuman abilities/powers etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## NO

Quote from Jon Bernthal via [**Screenrant**](http://screenrant.com/jon-bernthal-punisher-frank-castle-role/) quoting a GQ article

> “I’m working on The Punisher now. You know, this whole superhero-comic-book thing is something I had zero interest in being a part of. The guys that I really, really respect as actors seem to have kind of purposely stayed away from that. I don’t mean that I’m above that or anything, just that it was not for me. But then when I got to know a little bit about this character… He ain’t got a fucking cape. **He ain’t got any superpowers.** He’s a fucking tortured, angry father and husband who’s living in this unbelievable world of darkness and loss and torment. Frank Castle resonates with me.”

Also via [**AwardsDaily.com**](http://www.awardsdaily.com/tv/interview-jon-bernthal/)

> "I wasn’t desperately trying to get into the comic book world. [laughs] For me, it’s about the human being. **He has no superpower. His superpower is his humanity. It’s his drive, his rage, and his loss.** I could never have played this part if I weren’t a husband or father. Until you really understand what it’s like to love somebody more than yourself and to willingly give your life for them, only then can you understand what it would mean if they were taken from you."

Comment: Most would argue Frank long since lost his humanity.

Comment: The official confirmations from members of the production team made this answer run away with the "Accepted answer" grant

Comment: @cde: Frank is _angry_, a human emotion, because the loss of his family makes him _sad_, another human emotion. There are similarities with e.g. a child that throws a tantrum because you took away its toys. This child has not lost its humanity. Frank's reaction is essentially a militarily-inclined tantrum (due to his military experience and violent character), but the underlying principle for acting out is the same. Frank responds the way he does **because** he suffers from his emotions. The fact that Frank separates the innocent from the guilty (in his way), proves his humanity.

Answer (score 3):

Marvel [lists](http://marvel.com/universe/Punisher_(Frank_Castle)) Frank as having no superpowers.

His "unnatural" ability in combat and survival is similar, if not more pronounced in the comics. The Frank Caste we see in Daredevil season 2 is just starting his rounds as The Punisher. This is still his origin.

Frank is a war vet, and his skill set comes from there. He's highly skilled, exceptionally armed, and very unstable. He's a big ball of anger, crazy, and ammo.

Other than that there's no powers here, nor can I see them writing anything into his character. It's too much of a deviation from who The Punisher really is.

[image]

Comment: That's in the comics, I was asking about the Netflix adaptation, since they tend to make changes to their Marvel characters.